# Could not fetch map

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary

I have a news website in react js(class base component) and I I want to get all the API using `map()`.I have written the code below please solve it.

```
{this.state.articles.map((element)=>()={
Return (here I am retrieve a div.
)}}
```

But when I run this code the console respond that can not read the undefined map
Please help.

Comment: If your state required data that comes from asynchronous processing, you need to handle when you do not have the data *yet*. Either initialize to an empty array or test for `undefined` before trying to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

please try this `{this.state.articles && this.state.articles.map((element)=>()={ return (here I am retrieve a div. )}}` thanks